# Visual Studio Community 2015: Error 1402.Could not open key

Tags: windows-registry, visual-studio-2015, community

So I got the Error "Could not open key" When I manually track down the key and enable permission then run the installation again, it switches the key sub-folder and gives me the same error. Could ayone help?

Answer (score 0):

So before I could set the rights, I located the folder `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>Installer>UserData>S-1-5-18>Components` then I right clicked it and clicked Permissions, click Advanced, Changed the Owner to Administrators then checked "Replace owner on the subcontainers and Folders" then checked "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" and clicked apply :D there's a chance you'll have to check the first one, hit apply, then check the second and hit apply.